# IOError although file name is correct and in the same folder

Tags: pandas, pycharm, python-import, import-from-excel, ioerror

I imported an Excel file (.xlsx) with pandas, and it worked great.

Then, I tested my code with a copy of the same file (I changed something in its content to test something). I named it differently, and changed the name of the file in the code as well, and it worked great.

HOWEVER NOW - I tried to import the original file again (I didn't forget to change the name in the code as well) - and it doesn't recognizes it anymore!

I checked many times that the name of the file is identical to the one I wrote in the code, and that the .py file is in the same folder as the .xlsx file - I don't get it - why doesn't it work anymore?

**Please look at the attached screenshot**, where you can see the code, and also the actual file name and that the files are in the same folder (left side of the screenshot)

Please help me understand and fix the situation.

Thank you!

p.s - the "Invalid file name" message is what I wrote in the 'except' block after the 'try' block.

`except IOError:
    print("Invalid file name")`

[Screenshot showing file name matches in code + excel file and python file in the same folder][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPWhM.png**strong text**

Comment: Try getting rid of your manual `except IOError` handling, and see what the real error is. It could be that the file is there, but something else in the read process is failing. Alternatively, you could keep your error handling but add a `raise` command after the `print(...)` to re-raise the `IOError` you would otherwise swallow and ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! 
It actually was weirder than that... I resolved it and wrote the answer here.

Comment: Crazy! You should accept your own answer.

Comment: yeah totally!
I am actually new here and don't know how to accept my answer and close the thread... Do you know how?

Comment: Alas, I can't help. I am also new, and have never asked a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RESOLVED`
Has something to do with Right to Left languages aka Hebrew and Arabic... If your language is one of these and you face the same problem - try what I did

How I found out and what I did to fix it:
I tried to rewrite the file name, and when I started deleting it, I noticed the typing pointer is facing the left side (like in languages that write Right to Left)..
After deleting the entire file name I made sure my keyboard is set to English (my native language is Hebrew, which is Right to Left) - although as you saw, I did wrote the file name in English - weird... And then I wrote the file name again - exactly the same - and it worked!
Apparently some bug regarding RtL languages...

Hope it'll help someone in the future, or that Pycharm will fix the issue...